# Summing values in rows of matrices with same column name in R

Tags: r, merge

I need to turn these two matrices corresponding to (toy) word counts:

```
     a hope to victory win
[1,] 2    1  1       1   1
```

and

```
     a chance than win
[1,] 1      1    1   1
```

where the word "a" appears a combined number of 3 times, and the word "win" appears 2 times (once in each matrix), into:

```
     a win chance hope than to victory
[1,] 3   2      1    1    1  1       1
```

where equally-named columns combine into a single column that contains the sum.

And,

```
     a hope to victory win different than 
[1,] 2    1  1       1   1         0    0
```

where first matrix is preserved, and the second matrix is attached at the end *but* with only unique column names and with all the row values equal to zero.

Comment: Does it need to be in a matrix? This seems like a much better task for a different data structure, such as a data.frame or a data.table. Here you're trying to use the column names to store data, when what you really want is a data.frame with two columns, 'word' and 'count'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you store this data in a data frame (Which is really recommended for this sort of data) the process is very simple.

(I'm including a conversion from that format, with any number of rows):

conversion:

```
newdf1 <- data.frame(Word = colnames(matrix1), Count = as.vector(t(matrix1)))
newdf2 <- data.frame(Word = colnames(matrix2), Count = as.vector(t(matrix2)))
```

now you can use rbind + dplyr (or data.table)

dplyr solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- rbind(newdf1,newdf2)
result <- df %>% group_by(Word) %>% summarise(Count = sum(Count))
```

the answer to your second question is related,

```
result2 <- rbind(newdf1,data.frame(Word = setdiff(newdf2$Word,newdf1$Word), Count = 0))
```

(the data.table solution is very similar, but if you're new to data frames and grouping/reshaping, I recommend dplyr)

(EDITED the second solution so that it's actually giving you the unique entries)

Comment: I'm getting an error message: `Error in function_list[[i]](value) : could not find function "group"` when running `df %>% group(Word) %>% summarise(Count = sum(Count))`. I posted the entire code [here](https://github.com/RInterested/Scrapbook/blob/master/in%20progress) in case it's a problem of lists vs data.frames that I can't see at this point.

Comment: woops, that should be `group_by`